# Creating zip file containing the files with UTF-8 encoding name in PHP using /usr/bin/zip

Tags: php, linux, utf-8, zip, non-ascii-characters

I'm creating and downloading a zip file using `/usr/bin/zip` in PHP. The problem is that the zip file contains the csv files with the non-ASCII file names. I got the zero-byte file downloaded and the file is not valid.

```
chdir($tmp_dir); // this is the directory where the files are written into

// CSV files that will be included in the zip file.
// assuming that the file already exist in $tmp_dir
$files = array();
$filename = "ショップ" . date("Ymd") . ".csv"; 
$fpath = $tmp_dir. DS . mb_convert_encoding($filename, "SJIS", "UTF-8");
$files[] = $fpath;

// The zip file to be created
$zip_file = "archive_" . date("Ymd").".zip";
$cmd = "/usr/bin/zip $zip_path *.csv";
exec($cmd);

// Force download
$fpath = $zip_file;
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $zip_path . '"');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
if ($this->isIE()) {
  header("Cache-Control:private");
  header("Pragma:private"); 
}
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fpath));
readfile($fpath);
```

I tried [ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php), but same problem occurs.

```
chdir($tmp_dir); // this is the directory where the files are written into

// CSV files that will be included in the zip file.
// assuming that the file already exist in $tmp_dir
$files = array();
$filename = "ショップ" . date("Ymd") . ".csv";
$fpath = $tmp_dir. DS . mb_convert_encoding($filename, "SJIS", "UTF-8");
$files[] = $fpath; 

// The zip file to be created    
$zip_file = "archive_" . date("Ymd").".zip";    
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($zip_path, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $v) {
  $zip->addFile(basename($v));
}
$zip->close();

// Force download
$fpath = $zip_file;
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $zip_path . '"');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
if ($this->isIE()) {
  header("Cache-Control:private");
  header("Pragma:private"); 
}
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fpath));
readfile($fpath);
```

Is there any workaround for this? When I removed the Japanese characters from the file name, it is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using a function [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to convert the file names to the proper charset.

```
$filename = iconv('SJIS', 'CP392//TRANSLIT', "ショップ" . date("Ymd") . ".csv");
$fpath = $tmp_dir. DS . $filename;
```

This means that it converts the input charset [SJIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS) to the output charset [CP392](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_932) for the file name. CP392 is a [code page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) for [Shift JIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS).

> Code page 932 (abbreviated as CP932, also known by the IANA name
>   Windows-31J) is Microsoft's extension of Shift JIS to include NEC
>   special characters (Row 13), NEC selection of IBM extensions (Rows 89
>   to 92), and IBM extensions (Rows 115 to 119). The coded character sets
>   are JIS X0201:1997, JIS X0208:1997, and these extensions. Windows-31J
>   is often mistaken for Shift JIS: while similar, the distinction is
>   significant for computer programmers wishing to avoid mojibake, and a
>   good reason to use the unambiguous UTF-8 instead. The windows-31J name
>   however is IANA's and not recognized by Microsoft, which historically
>   has used shift_jis instead.